# MySQL Using output of a subquery in the case clause

Tags: mysql

I want to accomplish the following scenario.I want to use the output of a subquery in the case clause to generate separate subqueries . Like this :

```
 select * from
   (case when min_id > 10 
            (
               select min(id) as min_id from t1 
            )
         then
         select * from t1 
         else
         select * from t2
   ) as t3
```

select min(id) as min_id from t1 is the inner subquery , I need to choose a query to execute based on the value of min(id) . If min(id) > 10 run some query otherwise choose another query to run.
Is there a way to do this in MySql

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (select min(id) from t1) > 10
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE COALESCE((select min(id) from t1), 0) <= 10
```

Both tables must have the same (or at least compatible) structure.

Comment: I need to execute either of the 2 queries and can't do a union

Comment: @AyanBiswas If so then you need to use stored procedure format - MySQL does not support anonymous code blocks.

Comment: @AyanBiswas *and can't do a union* Explain the reason please.